# Showing that all quadratic regular forms are isometric to the sum of one-dimensional and two-dimensional forms

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

I was given the following problem:

> Show that, in characteristic 2, every regular quadratic form is isometric to the sum of one-dimensional and two-dimensional forms

Since the question asks about $char(F)=2$, I'm unsure as to how to approach this problem: do I look for a specific isometry for all regular forms, or is there any theorem that I can utilize in order to solve this?